# div container's backgorund color doesn't cover all div content

Tags: html, css

I want all text "Text here for test" to be covered in green .
Right now only the top is green.
   Here is my code :

```css
.circle {
  background: #00ff00;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #00ff00">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://podio.com/abccapitalinvestmentscom/labs/apps/crew-agreements/items/1229" style="color: #0040ff">
    <div class="circle">
      <div style="padding-left:5px;">Text here for test</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `width` and `height` for circle class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you set height 10px on the circle and the `.circle` div contains the text. The parent div that has the bgColor will have the height of it's children. So it will cover only 10px. The text overflows because that's the default behavior.

So a simple solution would be to remove the `height:10px` from circle. Or change the HTML structure and include the text separately, not inside the `.circle` div

```css
.circle {
    background: #00ff00;
    width:10px;
   
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #00ff00">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://podio.com/abccapitalinvestmentscom/labs/apps/crew-agreements/items/1229" style="color: #0040ff"> 
    <div class="circle"><div style="padding-left:5px;">Text here for test</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `height: 10px;` from `.circle` class

```css
.circle {
  background: #00ff00;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #00ff00">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://podio.com/abccapitalinvestmentscom/labs/apps/crew-agreements/items/1229" style="color: #0040ff">
    <div class="circle">
      <div style="padding-left:5px;">Text here for test</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="background-color: #00ff00;">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://podio.com/abccapitalinvestmentscom/labs/apps/crew-agreements/items/1229" style="color: #0040ff">
    <div>
      <div style="padding:5px;">Text here for test</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```